# React Native iOS builds break on the command line until I build once in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcodebuild

I'm running react-native iOS debug builds and I can see that it runs `xcodebuild` commands. I find that whenever there are dependency updates, the `xcodebuild` commands fail.

The actual errors are inconsistent, but there is one point of consistency: if I open the workspace in Xcode and tell it to build without making any other changes, my build succeeds.

From that point on, my command line react native builds succeed too.

To my mind builds inside Xcode should be identical to xcodebuild from the command line. I don't want an editor that I only use for one button in my development workflow; I want to be able to use the command line alone.

I thought there might be some cleaning that Xcode does, so I've tried:

- cleaning out node_modules and build artifacts (`git clean -fdx`)
- clearing the yarn cache
- clearing the pod cache
- deleting Xcode derived data.

None of these made the magic "open it up in Xcode and press the play button" difference.

What else could be different between my command line builds and my Xcode builds?

Comment: Not an expert in ios builds by any means, but the two things i've noticed i have to open xcode for are the initial teams, profile, dev account setup and your aforementioned dependency updates. It makes sense to me that the build commands doesn't deal with these two prerequisites. Profile setup and installing dependencies. One thing I know i've done to help with dependencies though is `pod install` on the command line. So it might be that that is something to try to resolve the dependency issue without having to open xCode.

Comment: Do you happen to have found solution to your problem ?

Answer (score -1):

I understand your frustration with the inconsistency between xcodebuild and Xcode. There are some possible reasons why they might behave differently, and some possible solutions to fix them.

One reason is that xcodebuild and Xcode might use different versions of the Xcode command-line tools. You can check this by running `xcode-select -p` in the terminal and comparing it with the path shown in **Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools**. If they are different, you can either change the path in Xcode or use `sudo xcode-select -s <path>` to switch the command-line tools version in the terminal1.

Another reason is that xcodebuild and Xcode might have different build settings or environment variables. You can compare them by running `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` in the terminal and looking at the Build Settings tab in Xcode. If there are any differences, you can either modify them in Xcode or use `-xcconfig <file>` or `-exportOptionsPlist <file> options` to specify a configuration file for xcodebuild2.

A third reason is that **xcodebuild** and **Xcode** might have different schemes or targets. You can check this by running `xcodebuild -list` in the terminal and looking at the Scheme menu in Xcode. If there are any differences, you can either create or edit schemes in Xcode or use `-scheme <name>` or `-target <name> options` to specify a scheme or target for **xcodebuild3**.

A fourth reason is that xcodebuild and Xcode might have different dependencies or frameworks. You can check this by looking at the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section in the General tab of your project settings in Xcode, and comparing it with the output of `xcodebuild -showBuildDependencies` in the terminal. If there are any differences, you can either add or remove frameworks or libraries in Xcode or use `-framework <name> or -library <name> options` to specify frameworks or libraries for **xcodebuild4**.

A fifth reason is that **xcodebuild** and **Xcode** might have different **caches** or **derived data**. You can check this by looking at the Derived Data location in **Xcode > Preferences > Locations**, and comparing it with the output of `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | grep DERIVED_DATA_DIR` in the terminal. If they are different, you can either change the location in Xcode or use `-derivedDataPath <path> option` to specify a derived data path for xcodebuild5. You can also try to clean the caches or derived data by using `xcodebuild clean` or `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` commands in the terminal, or by using `Product > Clean Build Folder` menu in Xcode.